# Strange window behavior when browsing Versions

Tags: cocoa, window, osx-lion, version, versions

I'm trying to implement Versions in my Cocoa app. Versioning just works well, the only problem I'm experiencing is when I want to restore a version from the versions browser (with all versions shown in the time machine style).

Setting the option in IB "Visible at Launch" causes the following problem: when browsing through the windows in the versions browser, the actual window gets instantly bigger and then it gets its size back when the clicked window is reached.

Another problem happens when I delete a version: the current window (i.e. the window on the left side) just disappears, and then also the frontmost version window becomes transparent. I noticed this also happens when creating a new project from scratch ...

Is there something I am missing? I would be very grateful for any tip on how to resolve this!

Comment: Can you post some screenshots or a video somewhere? It's hard to visualise this.

Comment: You can see a demo of the issues here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BNUBhhmJNqs

Comment: That video is marked as private, you need to make it unlisted or public if you want us to be able to watch it.

Comment: I'm sorry, it's the first time I upload to Youtube ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured it out. This is a bug of Xcode, running the app by double-clicking on the executable instead of inside Xcode there are no problems.

Comment: I've noticed windows disappearing in the versions browser too. It only seems to happen when "Allow debugging when using the documents Versions Browser" is checked in your Debug scheme options (NSDocumentRevisionsDebugMode=YES).

Answer (score 1):

As stated by @mrwalker This happens only when `Allow debugging when using the documents Versions Browser` is checked.

To remove this commandline option uncheck `Allow debugging when using the documents Versions Browser` in Xcode `Edit Scheme -> Run -> Options`.